# Operation with Arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have an array of binary numbers in Python like this:

```
binary = [1,1,0,1,1,0,0]
```

So, I wanna have a method to return how many times is a sequence of binary number, for example:

```
binary = [1,1,0,1,1,0,0]
```

must return 4, because there are 1 sequence of 'twice 1', after there is a sequence of  'one 0', then there are a sequence of 'twice 1' and finally a sequence of 'twice 0'

other example:

```
binary = [1,0,0,1,1,1,1]
```

must return 3, because there is 1 sequence of 'one 1', after there are a sequence of  'twice 0', finally there are a sequence of 'four 1s.'

Thank you so much.

Comment: In this moment I'm tried, if i can make it, I will share the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any ideas how to improve?

```
def countSeq(src):
  last = src[0]
  count = 0
  current = 1
  while current < len(src):
    if src[current] != last:
      count += 1
      last = src[current]
    current += 1
  return count + 1 # last
```

Test:

```
>>> countSeq([1,1,0,1,1,0,0])
4
>>> countSeq([1,0,0,1,1,1,1])
3
```

Comment: `countSeq([])` => `IndexError: list index out of range`. Also, this is much cleaner with a for loop, and you should initialise count to 1 except for the case that `src` has length 0 (where you just return `0` immediately).

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm going to try improving your code Mux, and share it again, because this is an exercise of Optimization Computational, and my solutions are very bad in performance.

Comment: U'r welcome, also about performance: `len(itertools.groupby(src))` as (mhawke offered) might be faster

Comment: @Mux: `groupby()` might give variable performance depending on the length of the input - it does a lot of work unrelated to counting sequences plus there will be overhead in evaluating the list so that the length can be determined. I think that a properly written dedicated function will be faster.

Answer (score 4):

This is trivial with `itertools.groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby

binary_lists = [[1,1,0,1,1,0,0],
                [1,0,0,1,1,1,1],
                '1111111111',
                '1',
                [0],
                [1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
                [],
                '',
                'aaccgta']

for bits in binary_lists:
    print '{} : num sequences = {}'.format(bits, len(list(groupby(bits))))
```

**Output**:

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0] : num sequences = 4
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1] : num sequences = 3
1111111111 : num sequences = 1
1 : num sequences = 1
[0] : num sequences = 1
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1] : num sequences = 7
[] : num sequences = 0
 : num sequences = 0
aaccgta : num sequences = 5
```

Comment: @Carlos: it is a bit of a party trick, and the performance might not be the best if that is your requirement.